# Can I get Vagrant to keep the insecure keys?

Tags: vagrant

It seems that Vagrant generates a new key pair if it detects insecure ones. Is it possible to prevent that behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Yes](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html):

```
# By default, Vagrant 1.7+ automatically inserts a different
# insecure keypair for each new VM created. The easiest way
# to use the same keypair for all the machines is to disable
# this feature and rely on the legacy insecure key.
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

For instance... My current "quickie testing" Vagrantfile looks like:

```
C:\Users\monsterkill\vagrant>cat Vagrantfile
# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
        config.vm.define "vagrant1" do |vagrant1|
                vagrant1.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
                vagrant1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
                vagrant1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
                vagrant1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
        end
end
```

Comment: Ah that wording is a lot clearer than the docs here https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html, cool.

Comment: Yeah, isn't it? I was lucky, I ran into this a number of weeks ago when I wanted to automate deploying Vagrant test boxes in order to automate some ansible automation, so to speak. (Yes, Skynet is coming.)

Comment: More or less what I'm doing, except I'm trying to get ansible to run on windows for our front end guy. Which of course fails in all kinds of interesting and terrible ways.

Comment: Ansible is not very nice on Windows. What I do is I have a nice ubuntu virtualbox as ansible host (which makes things much easier) and a bunch of vagrant testboxes. I set the vagrant boxes up so that they auto-LAN, then I can use ansible from the "ansible server" ubuntu vbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by adding this single line `config.ssh.insert_key = false`

Here is the sample:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

end
```